# How to find the number of lattice points in a region bounded by 3 points(a triangle)?

Tags: geometry, integers

Can someone tell me any tips on finding the number of lattice points in a triangular region(or any region)? I was looking at a theorem called [Pick's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) and I wanted to know if there was an easy way to find the value of $i$ in the formula other than counting them manually(like a formula).

Thanks!

Comment: Is the final goal to calculate the area of the triangle? If so, there are easier ways to do so, like using the cross product. If the final goal is to calculate the number of lattice points on the interior, then actually using Pick’s Theorem but reversed (i.e. calculate the area then solve for $i$) might not be a bad way of doing it.

Comment: @paulinho So I should just solve for $i$ in terms of $A$ and $b$?

Comment: If your goal is to calculate $i$, then yes, this is one way of doing it. (Note that $b$ is fortunately not too difficult to compute.) But if the end goal is to calculate $A$, then of course you shouldn’t use this method.

Comment: @paulinho Yes I'm just trying to find the number of lattice points in a triangular region. I just gave Pick's Theorem as an example. So is using Pick's Theorem the easiest way to solve for these type of problems or should I be aware of some easier method?

Comment: There are probably better ways to do this, though doing it this way is pretty feasible. Unfortunately no other ways are coming to me right now.